# how to access google maps marker object properties javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

What I am trying to achieve is to add custom markers to a map and then change their properties. For example I have put a marker on the map with a infowindow attached, how do I access that inforwindow object(is it an object? i dont know) and update the text it is displaying?

The code below allows me to drop markers on a map, but I cant figure out how to then access these markers and edit the marker's properties?

any help appreciated.

```
function initialize() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: {lat: -45.730, lng: 170.579}
        });

        // This event listener calls addMarker() when the map is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            addMarker(event.latLng, map);
        });


    }

    // Adds a marker to the map.
    function addMarker(location, map) {


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,

            icon: 'path to image',
            map: map
        });
        var markerBubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'text in bubble'

    });

   markerBubble.open(map, marker);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: This could be helpful to you.
http://ngmap.github.io. Basically, it's using AngualrJS, and you don't event have to code any Javascript for simple operation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, you can either decide you change your marker in your addmarker() function, as you have your marker object there. When I did this I saved all my markers into an array so that I could change them at will. Look into the Marker class documentation, it shows you all kinds of parameters you can configure (e.g. color, shape, size, etc)

What you can also do is just return your marker at the end of your addmarker cunction, and put it in a variable in your listener event.

Note: Markers have on click events too, you can bind mouse clicks to markers that you make, so let's say you want to be able to remove then, you could bind this to a left click on your created marker.